# How can I get query string values in JavaScript - part 2?

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

The following is a [question now closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?page=2&tab=active#tab-top)

Is there a plugin-less way of retrieving query string values via jQuery (or without)?

If so, how? If not, is there a plugin which can do so?

Would someone be so kind as to let me answer my own question because there's no good answer in the other bloody answer? You know what, never mind. I'm not going to fight to be "allowed" to post a good solution. What's in that for me? Just a lot of annoyance, that's what.

Comment: I don't understand - [this exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?page=2&tab=active#tab-top) has been asked and discussed with 90 answers.  Why ask it again?

Comment: No good answer has been given. I don't really know what makes it so hard, but regexes, pages of code or fulltext parsing really aren't required.

Comment: If I could /add/ my answer there, that would work. But I can't since it's closed (why?)

Comment: Apparently the referred-to duplicate has been locked by a moderator as it is now a FAQ/wiki post. You can edit any such post that has been made Community wiki, but you cannot add new answers. If you feel that none of the answers are good enough, then you could proceed by carefully editing the answer that is most alike to what you believe is correct, and append additional details there, to make the answer more complete.

Comment: My solution is different enough to warrant another answer. I think it's worthy of metaoverflow post to figure out how to best deal with it. The problem is, it's not my problem. I want to help others, I want to build a reference of good solutions to problems, but it's really no use to me.

Comment: @Lodewijk In my opinion a community wiki shouldn't be closed especially in the IT field, which evolves and changes really quickly. Anyway, there are some answers which don't use either regexps or aren't unnecessarily long. have you seen this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21152762/985454